# NullPointerException from gradle when running react-native run-android

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

When trying to run react-native run-android I am getting this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

I just updated my OS to El Capitan 10.11.6. It was working fine this morning so I am just wondering what could be wrong.

Modifying the client.js to add the --stacktrace flag to the gradle command doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the package I was requiring as a dependency was trying to also include firebase that is really big. By narrowing down to the exact packages I needed and only those, I was able to have the build to pass successfully.